# Android device not detected

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

MY android device VIVO Y15 is not detected in android studio.
here is what i have tried

[image]

Enable developer option and usb debugging
updated the driver to google usb driver
Although in device manager list under android device section  an Android adb interface appears , but in the list of troubleshoot it shows:

[image]

> Android ADB interface not recognised as android device

Answer (score 0):

i think you must, uninstall adb,
and try do this

1. right click
2. update driver
3. Browse my  computer for driver software
4. Let Me Pick.....
5. and search MTP USB Device

if device manager showing like this, I hope to help you
[image: device manager]

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works you can give this a try : https://adb.clockworkmod.com/ This supports a lot of Android OEMs.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have this tab open in your chrome to debug your webviews.

[chrome://inspect/#devices](https://chrome://inspect/#devices)

Closing this tab helped my Android Studio to detect my device.